# AngularJS how to setup two way data binding between a service and a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How would you on connect two way data binding between a service and controller?  I've looked at a couple posts, such as [How to make two-way data binding between service and controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281669/how-to-make-two-way-data-binding-between-service-and-controller), but I don't understand the answer.  Can someone provide a simple, high-level explanation or example?  I've looked into using $watch, but I've also noticed a lot of people saying it shouldn't be used in controllers ie. [Angular JS - you probably shouldn't use $watch in your controllers](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/10/title.html), which just adds to the confusion since I don't know where else I would add it.

Included dependencies from main app.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp', [
        'ngRoute',
        'app.controller',
        'app.service',
        'component.navbar'
    ]);
})();
```

Included dependencies from navbar component

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    /* Navbar Component */

    angular.module('component.navbar', [
        'component.navbar.controller',
        'component.navbar.directive',
        'component.navbar.service'
    ])

    .run(function( NavbarService ) {
        NavbarService.getJSON();
    });

})();
```

Navbar component snippets

```
(function() {
   'use strict';

   angular.module('component.navbar.service', [])

   .factory('NavbarService', ['$http', function( $http ) {

       var navbarJSON = [];
       var active = 0;


        var getJSON = function() {

            return $http.get('app/data/navlinks.json')
                .success( function( data ) {
                    navbarJSON = data;
                });
        }

        var getData = function(  ) {

            return navbarJSON;
        }

        var setActive = function( index ) {
            active = index;
        }

        var getActive = function() {
            return active;
        }

        return {
            getJSON: getJSON,
            getData: getData,
            setActive: setActive,
            getActive: getActive
        }

    }]);

})();

(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('component.navbar.controller', [])

    .controller('NavbarController', ['$scope', 'NavbarService', function( $scope, NavbarService ) {

        $scope.navbarData = NavbarService.getJSON();

        $scope.active = NavbarService.getActive();

        $scope.setActive = function( index ) {
            //$scope.active = $scope.navbarData[index]
            NavbarService.setActive( index );
        }

    }]);

})();
```

Comment: The first link you posted is using a different language called [Dart (read more)](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dart/info) which you are not using. Is the code you posted not working? Is it working and you just want a code review or a better way to do it?

Comment: It doesn't work.  I thought that setting the active navbar link would promote two way databinding for $scope.active.  From what I've read I need to use $watch?  but I don't know where I should be using it, especially with articles that say not use it in controllers due to poor testability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have just chosen to pass the service as a `$scope` property and then use its methods as it is:

**Javascript**

*Controller*

```
.controller('NavbarController', ['$scope', 'NavbarService', function( $scope, NavbarService ) {

    NavbarService.getJSON();
    $scope.navbar = NavbarService;

}]);
```

**HTML** (Example)

```
<nav ng-controller="NavbarController">
  <a ng-repeat="link in navbar.getData()"
     ng-class="{'active': navbar.getActive() == $index}"
     ng-click="navbar.setActive($index)">
     {{link.label}}
  </a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your service module to your controller module first

**angular.module('component.navbar.controller', ['component.navbar.service'])**

and I can't see where you have called **NavBarService.getJSON ()**, so called it first to get the data.

Comment: sorry that was a typo when I was formatting the code in the editor.  I've update getData to getJSON.

Comment: Please import your service module to your controller module first

Comment: Hi Toan, I've added my projects dependencies to my example for you to reference.

Comment: Hi @mtpultz, could you please change  angular.module('component.navbar.controller', []) to  angular.module('component.navbar.controller', ['component.navbar.service'])

Comment: Okay, I've done that, but I'm not sure what that does compared to how I've added the project dependencies.

Comment: Could you please tell me what happen then? You can see the detail from the console ( F12 if you use Chrome)

Comment: Nothing appears to happen, no errors at least, but I'd expect that since the service is already added as a dependency to the project and being consumed as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just expose `active` in your service? If you need getter/setter, use implicit ones.

Regarding the suggestion not to use `$watch` in controllers. That is a pretty generic statement. If `$watch` is the right tool, use it. If you can achieve the same with an event listener, do that.

In your case your service could broadcast an event on the root scope to signal a change of state. You could listen for that event in your controller and update your value instead of using `$watch`.